# Updating core with Composer, differences, and why --with-dependencies fails

Tags: composer

I'm a Drupal novice and have been playing around with it for the last few months. It seems like every 'how-to' article tells you a different way and a reason not to do it the other way.

I am a sysadmin for some developers and don't plan on getting too far in over my head but want to successfully support Drupal with Core and Module updates as needed for security.

I set up some Drupal instances on a test vm and have some questions here with my guesses on the answers and would appreciate confirmation and perhaps a little guidance.

Recently I installed Drupal 8 using Composer with the below command and it installed 8.8.5:

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project
```

composer.json has this:

```
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
```

(Q1) Later I ran this and it didn’t update Core at all despite 8.9.5 being available:

```
composer update drupal/core-recommended –with-dependencies
```

(A1) I assume this is because drupal/core-recommended has dependencies that aren’t updated by this command so it didn't update anything. I don't get why the "with dependencies" flag didn't force it to update them though.

(Q2) I reverted to a vm snapshot back to 8.8.5 and tried this and it updated Core to 8.8.8:

```
composer update drupal/*
```

(A2) I assume because Core >8.8.8 has unmet dependencies so it stopped at 8.8.8.

(Q3) I reverted back to the 8.8.5 snapshot and tried this and it updated Core to 8.9.5:

```
composer update
```

(A3) because this updates everything along with all dependencies, but how is this different from Q1 above?

[This says a workaround](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer) for the dependency problem is to specify each dependency along with Core. (eg: composer update drupal/core "symfony/*" --with-dependencies).   There are a number of dependencies showing as ‘prohibits’ so this would be a pretty long command. So why do it this way and not just use “composer update”? Isn't it more or less the same thing?

I'm guessing it really depends on each use case but what is the general best practice? I don't expect our Drupal instance to have a lot of modules because I'm told the developers plan on doing a lot of the work on the front end.